# Convert doc byte array to pdf byte array in angular

Tags: angular, file-upload

I need to browse doc,pdf file and show preview before uploading. so I converted to byte arrays.pdf I achieved using sending byte array to pdf-viewer.But cannot find for doc.So I planned to convert doc byte array to pdf byte array and preview it.Please help I am new to angular.

```
 this.file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();      
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.previewUrl = reader.result.  //to extract bytes array of doc
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer

Comment: ngx-doc-viewer not help for not uploaded doc file.I tried it first